# How to implement abstract class like functionality in Rust?

Tags: rust, design-patterns

I recently learned Rust, and for my first larger scale practical project I'm making a terminal based game with `crossterm`. Now, I come from the OOP world of Java and C++, so I'm having some trouble adjusting to Rust.

If I was making this in a OOP language, I would have a `GameWorld` abstract class that would define different "worlds", such as the lobby, metaworld, dungeons, and the menu. The `GameWorld` would have methods such as `draw()` and `tick()`.

Then, for each of those worlds I would then define a subclass, so I would have `DungeonWorld` and `MenuWorld`, etc...

However in Rust, my original idea was to define a `World` trait. Then I could define structs for each world and have them implement `World`. But that requires major use of `Box<dyn World>` which seems to be discouraged by the community and slow to execute.

In theory, what I would like is to be able to define different `impl` blocks for each instance of a `World` struct.

This is a stripped down version of what I currently have.

```rust
let game = game::get_game();
loop {
    let result = if event::poll(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000 / TICK_SPEED))
        .expect("Error checking input")
    {
        game.current_world.update(Some(event::read().expect("Error reading input.")))
    } else {
        game.current_world.update(None)
    };

    if !result {
        break;
    }
    game.curent_world.draw();
}
////////////
pub trait World {
     fn draw(&self);
     fn update(&self, event: Option<Event>);
}
////////////
struct Game {
    current_world: Box<dyn World>,
}

struct MenuWorld {}
impl World for MenuWorld {
    fn draw(&self) {}
    fn update(&self, event: Option<Event>) {}
}

pub fn get_game() -> Game {
    Game {
        current_world: Box::new(MenuWorld {})
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered turning the different kinds of worlds into an `enum` and implementing the appropriate traits for that? I'd also say that dynamic dispatch in Rust is only "slow to execute" compared to static dispatch in Rust, not necessarily when compared to dynamic dispatch in another language.

Comment: @isaactfa I did see this kind of approach in an answer to another SO question, however I'm not sure if that would work well, since each world will have a lot of functionality and different methods and properties.

Comment: That is indeed a drawback. The usual way to do it is making a struct for each world, implementing the traits for the structs, making an enum where each variant wraps one of those structs, implementing the traits for the enum by simply delegating to the struct. It's a little boilerplate-y, but it keeps everything nice and separate. There's actually a crate that can generate a lot of that code for you: https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/

Comment: You say Box<dyn World> is slow, but have you measured it? Rust makes costs explicit, but that doesn't mean the costs are "slow." Dynamic dispatch (using trait objects like `dyn World`) may be slower than static dispatch, but it also may not depending on your use case. The other languages you're coming from also use dynamic dispatch under the hood, Rust just makes it obvious what's happening.

You can definitely use enums and static dispatch if desired, but if dynamic dispatch will make your code simpler and more maintainable, don't write it off without measuring the performance impact.

Comment: @MPlanchard No, I have not, that is merely what I thought from searching online. If that is so, then my current approach is correct?

Comment: @sean I would start with `Box<dyn World>`. Once you have reached a stage at which performance starts to matter (which is actually fairly unlikely for a term-based game), you can benchmark it. FWIW, `Box<dyn World>` has basically the same performance characteristics as any object in Java.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks for the suggestion, would the implementation look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/tuta-amb/b7a4825729d830071237cddf5e52baa9)? Also, is there a name for this design patten?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I don't think it specifically has a name. It's just using static dispatch instead of dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have solved this problem, with two solutions

a) Use something like this crate https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/

b) Continue with `Box<dyn World>` because it isn't that bad and is what other languages do under the hood.